# Is there a safe way to Eval In ruby? Or a better way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eval, code-injection

When a user uses my application, at one point they will get an array of arrays, that looks like this:

```
results = [["value",25], ["value2",30]...]
```

The sub arrays could be larger, and will be in a similar format. I want to allow my users to write their own custom transform function that will take an array of arrays, and return either an array of arrays, a string, or a number. A function should look like this:

```
def user_transform_function(array_of_arrays)
  # eval users code, only let them touch the array of arrays
end
```

Is there a safe way to sandbox this function and eval so a user could not try and execute malicious code? For example, no web callouts, not database callouts, and so on.

Comment: "Is there a safe way to Eval in xyz?" - no.

Comment: How do you ensure that the output of the user function is an array of arrays, string, or a number? Is that part of this question? Or, is it irrelevant?

Comment: It is part of what I want. I thought maybe because my input was so specific, and my output was so specific that it would make it easier to sandbox, and check the result to make sure that it what I expect.

Comment: I would say: the best way to do this is to make a small language parser yourself so you know exactly what is happening, and if it is legal.

Comment: I agree…oh so much more work to do. At least it is fun. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you will use `eval`, it will never be safe. You can at least have a look in the direction of `taint` method.

What I would recommend is creating your own DSL for that. There is a great framework in Ruby: http://treetop.rubyforge.org/index.html. Of course, it will require some effort from your side, but from the user prospective I think it could be even better.

Comment: I agree this would be better I am just wondering if it may be far to much over head

Comment: might be, I see. On the other hand, it's a great exercise and might be fun to implement.

Comment: With the death of RubyForge, is this the appropriate new link? https://github.com/cjheath/treetop

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: I can not guarantee that this is truly safe!**

You might be able to run it as a separate process and use [ruby $SAFE](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/taint.html), however this does not guarantee that what you get is safe, but it makes it harder to mess things up.

What you then would do is something like this:

```
script = "arr.map{|e| e+2}" #from the user.
require "json"

array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
begin
    results = IO.popen("ruby -e 'require \"json\"; $SAFE=3; arr = JSON.parse(ARGV[0]); puts (#{script}).to_json' #{array.to_json}") do |io|
        io.read
    end 
rescue Exception => e
    puts "Ohh, good Sir/Mam, your script caused an error."
end

if results.include?("Insecure operation")
    puts "Ohh, good Sir/Mam, you cannot do such a thing"
else
    begin
        a = JSON.parse(results)
        results = a
    rescue Exception => e
        puts "Ohh, good Sir/Mam, something is wrong with the results."
        puts results
    end
end

       conquer_the_world(results) if     results.is_a?(Array)
do_not_conquer_the_world(results) unless results.is_a?(Array)
```

---

**OR**

You could do this, it appears:

```
def evaluate_user_script(script)
  Thread.start {
    $SAFE = 4
    eval(script)
  }    
end
```

But again: I do not know how to get the data out of there.

Comment: **Note:** The SAFE level should be at 4, however I could not figure out how to get the results back unless I lowered it to 3. There might be some good way to achieve this. If anyone know of a way, then please let us know! :)

Comment: Yah it would be great to know if I can get the value out. Then I can test the results to find out if they are what I would ever allow.